# UIActivityViewController with HTML

Tags: html, ios, ios6, sharing

When I pass a string containing HTML content as an array element to the `UIActivityViewController initWithActivityItems` method it doesn't present it as HTML in the selected 'share' controller, but instead presents the HTML source (i.e. the markup rather than interpreting it).

And while I can understand why it would do this for share targets that don't support html content, it won't interpret it for things like email either, which do (previously this would be done by setting the `isHTML` property to `YES` on the `MFMailComposeController`).

Should I waste my time creating a `UIActivityItemProvider` that returns custom content based on the 'activity type' or is there really no way to get the mail controller presented by the `UIActivityViewController` to interpret the content as HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What activities are you looking to support? Activity types are dependent on the service, and they're pretty [clearly defined](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActivity_Class/Reference/Reference.html). There's no way for services to know that a string is a plain text or marked-up text, for example--you might want to paste HTML code on purpose.

You can always do things the old-fashioned way and copy plain text and HTML to the pasteboard, or call the mail composer directly, or whatever you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: As I mentioned in my reply to the other answer, I did as you suggested and didn't use the UIActivityViewController.

Answer (score 54):

In my testing if the string begins "<html><body>" and ends "</body></html>" then it is treated as HTML.

If you want a good result with the non-HTML-aware sharing services you need to instead use an object that implements the [UIActivityItemSource](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIActivityItemSource_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIActivityItemSource) protocol and returns the HTML string when from `-activityViewControllerPlaceholderItem:` and from `-activityViewController:itemForActivityType:` if the activity is `UIActivityTypeMail` and `nil` otherwise.

A second [UIActivityItemSource](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIActivityItemSource_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIActivityItemSource) that returns a suitable non-HTML string from `-activityViewControllerPlaceholderItem:` and from `-activityViewController:itemForActivityType:` if the activity is not `UIActivityTypeMail` (and `nil` if it is) is the rest of the puzzle.

I recommend against having one object do both jobs, as the `UIActivity` engine is entitled to make different decisions based on whether the placeholder item appears to be HTML or not.

Comment: I have this and it's not interpreted as HTML. Any ideas?  activityItemProvider.appStoreURL=@"<html><body> <a href=\"http://www.w3schools.com\">Visit W3Schools.com!</a> </body></html>";

Comment: Note that the HTML will be shown literally in the Message, Twitter, and Facebook actions.

Comment: @KevinChen see modified answer

Comment: Just to possible spare some time for someone trying to modify the email's font: Insert a `<div>` with the given font style _after_ the `<body>` tag like in following example: `<html><body><div style='font-family: sans-serif;'><p>Hello</p></div></body></html>`

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried any of these, but they seemed reasonable for your goal when I was getting myself familiar with UIActivityViewController.

1) You could write the HTML source to a local file, e.g., `my_mail_message.html`, then build an `NSURL` object with that file, e.g., `[NSURL URLWithString:@"file://my_mail_message.html"]`, and then use that `NSURL` object as an element of the `activityItems` array that you feed to `initWithActivityItems:applicationActivities:`.

2) If you know the intended recipient, e.g., `foo@example.com`, you could possibly build an `NSURL` object with the `mailto` scheme and the HTML source as the `body`, like so: `mailto:foo@example.com?body={my HTML source goes here}`.
You should omit the curly braces `{}`. As before, you should then use that `NSURL` object as an element of the `activityItems` array.

Hope this gives you some ideas.

Comment: I did try passing in various types of objects when I was looking at this but I don't think I tried this specifically (an NSURL with the content that I wanted to be presented).  I'll look at this when I revisit it in the next app update, but for now I am not using the UIActivityViewController at all.

Comment: There is currently no way to set the recipient for mail message created through the UIActivityViewController, so let's not tell people that there is.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to make sure the first line of the HTML string is an  tag.

Comment: I do not know whether this is generally true or not, however in my testing if the string begins "<html><body>" and ends "</body></html>" then it is treated as HTML.

Comment: Works for me, at least for emails.