# Can you put a hyperlink in a UIActivityItemProvider?

Tags: ios, uiactivityviewcontroller

I have a huge link. I want to share this link when a user in my app posts to facebook from within the app. However my link is too large so I'd like to shorten it. Is there anyway (natively) I could have something like "Download the app HERE" where HERE redirects to my super long link?

Comment: possible duplicate of [UIActivityViewController with HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12658248/uiactivityviewcontroller-with-html)

Comment: What's not mentioned in the referenced answer is the possibility of using the new Social.framework to post specifically to Facebook.

Comment: It seems the only method for URLs in Social.framework is -(BOOL)addURL:(NSURL *)url, which doesn't look like it supports what I want to do (adding a link to a link).

Comment: May have to fall-back to using the [Facebook API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios) directly.  Which is more or less what the other link suggests as well :)

Comment: Dang, I need to do this for facebook,twitter, email, mms, etc.

Comment: Which is why activity provider (and social) don't have it.  Each service has a completely different (if any) way of doing it.

Comment: One thing you might consider, especially if you already have a server, is providing or using some kind of url shortening service such as [Google's](https://developers.google.com/url-shortener/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking to do really can't be done with UIActivityViewController since each service has a completely different mechanism for encoding/representing links.  Your best is probably to use some kind of URL shortening service such as [Google's](https://developers.google.com/url-shortener/)